# how to access td without class or id in ganon

Tags: php, html-parsing, ganon

My table is Like:

```
<table class="tl">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="tlr">
            <td><a href="link here" title="title here">abcd</a></td>
            <td class="tli"><img src="img src here" alt="English" class="icon"></td>
            <td>I WANT THIS TEXT</td>
            <td class="sn">12</td>
            <td class="ln">44</td>
            <td><div class="r0"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to access plaintext of 3rd `<td>` (`<td>I WANT THIS TEXT</td>`).

I am very confused that how to get this. 
Please help me

Comment: Is it always going to be the third?

Comment: yes. it's very popular site's html structure. so for now it is always going to be the 3rd.

Comment: You could take a look at using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ it's a PHP library that will read HTML from a URL/string and allow you to select parts of the HTML document just as you would using css, but in PHP rather than Javascript. It's regularly used in web scraping, which I get the impression is what you're trying to do.

Comment: I know how to use S_H_D parser, I did 100s of projects in it. ganon is what what I am interested now a days. I am new in ganon. there must be solution in ganon, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var text = $('.tlr td:nth-child(3)').text();
alert(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tl">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="tlr">
            <td><a href="link here" title="title here">abcd</a></td>
            <td class="tli"><img src="img src here" alt="English" class="icon"></td>
            <td>I WANT THIS TEXT</td>
            <td class="sn">12</td>
            <td class="ln">44</td>
            <td><div class="r0"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it's not working. I tried as per your code: `$element('tr.tlr td:nth-child(n)',3)->getPlainText();`

it said : `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPlainText() on null in /path here/index.php:166 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /path here/index.php on line 166`

Comment: this is jquery code. You are trying to get it with php?@JeetKalariya

Comment: yes, I tried it in php. can you tell me how can I transfer the td plaintext from js variable to PHP variable

Comment: Just post it with ajax. @JeetKalariya

Answer (score 0):

Following code for get all td datas from clicking any row.

```
 var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
 var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
 tbody.onclick = function (e) {
     e = e || window.event;
     var data = [];
     var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
     while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
         target = target.parentNode;
     }
     if (target) {
         var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");
         for (var i = 2; i < 3; i++) {
             data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
         }
     }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeet, you need to use [Jquery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)... Take a look at the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ready demo</title>
  <style>
  p {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>

  $( document ).ready(function() {
    alert($( "table tbody tr td:nth-child(3)" ).text());
  });

  </script>

</head>
<body>


<table class="tl">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="tlr">
            <td><a href="link here" title="title here">abcd</a></td>
            <td class="tli"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg" alt="English" class="icon"></td>
            <td>I WANT THIS TEXT</td>
            <td class="sn">12</td>
            <td class="ln">44</td>
            <td><div class="r0"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> 

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps...